# Are there any scenario where VMM will fail to inject an interrupt into a guest on Interrupt window exit?

Tags: x86, interrupt, virtualization, kvm, hypervisor

I am working on a custom Type 2 Hypervisor. My question is related to interrupt injection of emulated devices in the guest.

Scenario:
The guest did some `vmexit`, before the next `vmresume` VMM found out that there is a pending interrupt present in the emulated interrupt controller. VMM requests for `Interrupt Window Exit(IWE)` on the subsequent `vmresume`.
Once we get an `IWE` VMM writes the interrupt info into `VM-entry interruption-information field 4016H` and resumes guest execution.

Question:
Is it guaranteed that the interrupt will be injected in the guest and handled through the guest `IDT`?
Are there cases where interrupt injection can fail?

I am seeing a scenario where instead of going into the corresponding guest IDT entry, the guest resumes and starts executing something else in the guest kernel.

Details:
`Windows 64 bit guest, Intel VTx`

Comment: I removed the `[kvm]` tag because I thought adding `[x86]` was more important.  If your custom hypervisor is actually based closely on `kvm`, maybe re-add it and drop the `[intel]` tag?  (More people follow the [x86] tag than `[intel]`, and the VT-X instead of AMD Hyper-V is something you already specify in the question text.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It's similar to KVM in the sense that it's also a Type 2. I just wanted the question to have a proper audience reach.

Comment: I left in `[virtualization]` and `[hypervisor]`.  I don't know what tags @prl follows, but I assume it includes x86 so hopefully he sees this.  There are a couple SO `[x86]` / asm regulars familiar with x86 HW virtualization; I assume most of them follow the `x86` tag but IDK about the virtualization tags.  IDK how many people follow `[kvm]` but not any of the generic tags, and who would be interested in answering a question that *not* about KVM at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 3):

There are reasons that an interrupt cannot be injected, but they will cause vm entry failure; it will never just ignore the injected interrupt. Examples are if IF is clear or if the previous instruction loaded SS, so interrupts are blocked for one instruction. However, when those cases apply, you wouldn’t have gotten an interrupt window exit.

Probably  the interrupt wasn’t injected. One reason I can think of that that could happen is if  the vm-entry interrupt information field was set up to deliver a fault, so an interrupt can’t be delivered at the same time.

Comment: I’m not sure what happens if the interrupt being injected is the posted interrupt notification vector. I’ll try to find out.

Comment: We don't use Vt-d. I also print vm-entry interrupt information field before and after I inject the interrupt. I can see only bit 31 being cleared which is expected on an exit. The vector is still the same in the filed. This is what is confusing me so much.